# Cannot mix multi providers and regular providers Angular

Tags: angular

I am getting this error while implementing `APP_INITIALIZER`

> Error: Cannot mix multi providers and regular providers
>
> at throwMixedMultiProviderError (core.js:219)
>
> at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:11405)

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, isDevMode, APP_INITIALIZER } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, HttpHeaders, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';



export function initializeApp(http: HttpClient): Promise<void> {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('test');
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      deps: [HttpClient],
      useFactory: initializeApp,
 //   multi:true
     },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

I tried adding multi: true as well. It gives different error for that

> core.js:6456 ERROR TypeError: _this22.appInits[i] is not a function
> at _loop3 (core.js:27930)

Everything looks fine. Anything I am missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Step 1 : use `{multi:true}` , because that is what that error is complaining about.

Step 2: need to solve the true issue,  the _loop3 error. Now, I cannot see anything obviously wrong here, but I'm guessing you based your code of the Angular docs (https://angular.io/api/core/APP_INITIALIZER). What if you copied the examples there exactly, without modification... would that give the same error?